# symfony2 .htaccess redirect issue for one route

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

For learning purposes I am building a toy site with symfony.

When accessing the site in dev-mode via **app_dev.php** everything works fine.

Also in production mode everything works except for one uri "/music". Here I encounter a strange 404 error, since a redirect to "/music/" occurs.

After some research I tried several things as described below. But I always get the same error. Maybe anyone can give me a hint how to solve this.

---

Here is the log entry, note that it searches for a route matching "/music/", not "/music" as it was send to the server

> [2013-10-23 21:01:37] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /music/"" at /var/www/symfony/runamusic.de/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1883 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /music/\" at /var/www/symfony/runamusic.de/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1883, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:  at /var/www/symfony/runamusic.de/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:197)"} []

I checked permissions to app/cache/prod, they seem to be o.k.

I cleared the chache by both removing "app/cache/prod" manually and running `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Also running `php app/console router:match /music` gives the correct route

```
ludviki@ludviki-MacBook:/var/www/symfony/runamusic.de$ php app/console router:match /music
Route "runamusic_music_album_index" matches

[router] Route "runamusic_music_album_index"
Name         runamusic_music_album_index
Path         /music
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: Runamusic\MusicBundle\Controller\AlbumController::indexAction
Requirements NO CUSTOM
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/music$#s
```

When importing routes in "app/config/routing.yml" no prefixes are added (I read about redirect issues with prefixes)

```
...
runamusic_home:
    resource: "@RunamusicHomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

runamusic_music:
    resource: "@RunamusicMusicBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

runamusic_show:
    resource: "@RunamusicShowBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
...
```

Here is the route definition in "Bundle/.../config/routing.yml"

```
runamusic_music_album_index:
    pattern:  /music
    defaults: { _controller: RunamusicMusicBundle:Album:index }

runamusic_music_album_show:
    pattern:  /music/album/{title}
    defaults: { _controller: RunamusicMusicBundle:Album:show }
...
```

Renaming the pattern from **/music** to for example **/musica** works, no redirect here.

Redefining a pattern in another bundle to **/music** yields the same unwanted redirect to **/music/**.

Also any nonexisting Route I tried is redirected (no redirect from **/Music** to **/Music/**)

I am aware that a possible solution was to change the pattern for this route. But I would like to understand what is going wrong here to avoid this in the future.

Maybe an rewrite error in .htaccess?

Thanks for your help.

---

Edit 3: removed previous adds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found what caused this behaviour. I saved images needed for my **/music...** routes in the .../web/**music** folder which caused an url rewrite from **/music** to **/music/** . Moving the images to another destination (which won't become an uri...) solved the issue.

Comment: never thought of that :)

nice job

Answer (score 1):

```
app/console route:debug
```

and see what's the order of match :)

edit:

i'm looking at this

[Symfony Routing Component](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Matcher/Dumper/PhpMatcherDumper.php#L217)

do you see that !methods ? i guess it checks if there's at least a method (not ANY) to not redirect to a more descriptive match (though you have child routes form that base path)

try to set a valid method GET|POST or whatever you need (i think just GET)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I updated my question to give the order of the routes. I think the order is fine, or am I missing something?

Comment: I added GET method, still the same issue.Also I tried removing the .htaccess rewrite rules and browse using "/app.php/music", this works, so maybe it is a .htaccess issue. I append the .htaccess to my question, i'm not very familiar with this